# Use java8 streams to read in 1 file and write out 3 files based on some critera

Tags: java, java-8, stream

To be clear - the goal here is to use input AND output streams, so that I am not building up huge lists for output later.  I just want java to open the input file, and run through it, writing to the output files in semi-realtime as it goes through.

I am totally new to streams.  I understand the basic idea of streams, and lamba's etc, but don't know the details of implementation and syntax, etc.  (For instance I am confused by the :: syntax I see in some examples)...

In any case - below is an example that gets done basically what I want to do...

I'd like to know how to do it with stream interface so that the main file (which could be quite large) doesn't need to be in memory all at the same time.

Thanks!

```
        Set<String> set1 = fileToSet(file1);
        Set<String> set2 = fileToSet(file2);

        List<String> output1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> output2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> output3 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(inputPath)) {
                String subString = line.substring(0,10);

                if (set1.contains(subString)) {
                    output1.add(line);
                }
                else if (set2.contains(subString)) {
                    output2.add(line);
                }
                else {
                    output3.add(line);
                }
        }
//write out all 3 files from the collected lists
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `forEach` to handle each line and apply your actual logic in 
and you could also use a `BufferedWriter` to write the content of the line that matches with your logic :

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
     BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file1"));
     BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2"));
     BufferedWriter writer3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file3"))) {

        lines.forEach((line) -> {

            String subString = line.substring(0, 10);

            try {
                BufferedWriter writerToUse;
                if (set1.contains(subString)) {
                    writerToUse = writer1;
                } else if (set2.contains(subString)) {
                    writerToUse = writer2;
                } else {
                    writerToUse = writer3;
                }
                writerToUse.append(line);
                writerToUse.newLine();

              // lambda cannot throw checked exception not declared in the 
              // functional interface. So you have to catch IO exception in
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO error processing
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: The outputs shouldn't be added to lists, otherwise the memory usage will remain sky high.

Comment: thanks @davidxxx, like Kayaman suggests, I don't want to continue to add the outputs to lists, only to use tons of memory and wait until the end to write... I'd like to link up input and output streams so that the data just flows through and lines get put into the separate files in semi-realtime as it reads through.

Comment: Writing the lines out to `BufferedReaders` instead of adding to `Lists` would make this less memory hungry, if you're not using those lists for anything.

Comment: Well...yes, obviously. I'm running a fever.

Comment: @davidxxx do not forget new lines :)

Comment: @Vladimir It is a detail but it is better with :) Thanks.

Comment: One thing: it might be a good idea to put the sets into a map. The map value would be the writer. So you don't need that code duplication with if set1 write else if set write2....

Comment: @GhostCat  Hehe. Right. We thought the same thing. I wondered if handling the duplication could be a good thing but I deemed that even if in the absolute it was a good idea, it would change the code of the OP on too many aspects (I already changed with try with resources, streams, for each...) On my own code, I would do it of course ;-) Anyway, I edited with a slight refactoring that finally stays very close of the OP code.

Comment: Good idea. Already upvoted, so I can't do that again. Cheerio and talk again another day.

Comment: I thought that you had super powers here. See you dear colleague :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
    Files.lines(Paths.get(inputPath)).forEach(line -> {
        // do your logic with line
        ...
    });
```

You should also consider to write the filtered data directly into output files and do not collect it in the memory. Output files might be open prior the file reading.